# when i double click a record in a datagrid. another form will show to edit the record in grid

Tags: vb.net, datagrid

i want to know what to do if i want to double click my existing data in my datagrid and my edit form will show and all the records are in place in specific textbox.

i already have add delete module

Add code

```
If RequiredEntry() = True Then
        Return
    End If
    Try
        Dim cn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Ace.Oledb.12.0; Data Source=" & My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath.ToString() & "\BackUp\Database3.Accdb;")

        If cn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then cn.Open()

        Dim sSQL As String = "insert into [userinfo]([username],[password],[FirstName],[LastName],[Account]) values(@username,@password,@FirstName,@LastName,@Account)"

        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sSQL, cn)


        ' UserName
        If txtPassword.Text = txtConfirm.Text Then
            Dim username As OleDbParameter = New OleDbParameter("@username", OleDbType.VarWChar, 50)
            username.Value = txtUser.Text.ToString()
            cmd.Parameters.Add(username)
        Else
            MsgBox("Password not matched")

        End If

        'password
        Dim password As OleDbParameter = New OleDbParameter("@password", OleDbType.VarWChar, 50)
        password.Value = txtPassword.Text.ToString()
        cmd.Parameters.Add(password)


        'First Name
        Dim FirstName As OleDbParameter = New OleDbParameter("@FirstName", OleDbType.VarWChar, 50)
        FirstName.Value = txtFirstName.Text.ToString()
        cmd.Parameters.Add(FirstName)


        ' Last Name
        Dim LastName As OleDbParameter = New OleDbParameter("@LastName", OleDbType.VarWChar, 50)
        LastName.Value = txtLastName.Text.ToString()
        cmd.Parameters.Add(LastName)

        'Account

        Dim Account As OleDbParameter = New OleDbParameter("@Account", OleDbType.VarWChar, 50)
        Account.Value = cboAccount.GetItemText(cboAccount.SelectedItem)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(Account)



        If cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() Then
            cn.Close()
            MessageBox.Show("New User is Added successfully.", "Record Saved")
            Call clear()
            Me.Hide()
            FileMaintenance.Show()


        Else
            MsgBox("New User Addition Failed ", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Addition Failed")
            Return
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        Exit Sub
    End Try
```

and this is my delete code

```
Dim connString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Ace.Oledb.12.0; Data Source=" & My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath.ToString() & "\BackUp\Database3.Accdb;"
    Dim MyConn As OleDbConnection
    Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim ds As DataSet
    Dim tables As DataTableCollection
    Dim source1 As New BindingSource
    Dim rows As String


    Try
        MyConn = New OleDbConnection
        MyConn.ConnectionString = connString
        ds = New DataSet
        tables = (ds.Tables)
        rows = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value.ToString()
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Delete * from [userinfo] where ID=" & rows, MyConn)
        da.Fill(ds, "userinfo")
        Records_Load(sender, e)

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("cannot delete empty records")
    End Try
```

Comment: Where's the method to pull the data back, what are you stuck on its not clear?

Comment: im currently working on it. want to know some ideas how to pull back the data from database.